# Grails file downloads using ajax calls outside of views folders

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, download, jquery-forms-plugin

I am building a grails app that requires importing a web structure of full html (complete with navigation and its own js/css) to be able to add some functionality from the existing controllers using ajax calls.

So far everything has worked as expected, the imported html is visible at /webapp/ImportedHtml and every ajax url/js/css just needs extra attention depending on what its being pointed at (the grails app urls or the Imported html ulrs).

However my first problem comes in the form of a downloadable file call. Here is my code:

```html
 <form id="uploadForm"  action="asyncGetFiles"  method="post"> 
   <input id="testbutton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

A very simple form with a submit that triggers a javascript call provided by [Jquery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

```js
     $('#testbutton').click(function(){
        // Takes in a list of files to be downloaded from .downloads
        var downloads_container =new Array();
        $('.downloads').each(function(){
            downloads_container.push($(this).val());
        });
        var __onSuccess = function(data) {
            // Opens the request in a new window to prevent the current from being modified or redirected
            var OpenWindow=window.open('', '_blank');
            OpenWindow.document.write(data);
            OpenWindow.document.close();
            self.name="main";

        };
        var options = {

            success: __onSuccess,
            data : {
                result:''+downloads_container
            }
        //,                url : '../../dataCart/asyncGetFiles'

        };
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(options);
    }
```

My controller download code is pretty simple, it looks like this:

```java
 response.setContentType("application/zip")
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "pictureName" + "\"");
 response.outputStream << "whatever I dont care";
 return;
```

In summary my current code is organized like this

- /rootApp /webapp /htmlRoot /downloads /downloads.html

  - to the server it looks like
  - /rootApp /htmlRoot /downloads /downloads.html
  - the ajax url will look like this

    - ../ ../ controller/ asyncGetFiles
  - any calls to the ajax originated from here will result in no download triggering BUT the call being successful and rendering as a plain string

However if I set the same code to the controller's view folder

- /rootApp/controller/downloads.gsp

  - the ajax calls pointing to asyncGetFiles
  - the call will successfully trigger the download

### The question is: Why is the download not triggering in the first scenario?

I've no idea where to look for information on how to fix this :/